# ConnectionManager.onChannelMessage() received message with different connectionSerial, but same message id as a previous; discarding

Tags: ably-realtime

Using Ably Realtime for a web based reservation system.

I'm getting a few errors in the js console consistently, though everything is working properly.

Basically, there is a date selector and when a visitor selects a date, I set a global variable `day` to the date (something like `2018-05-25`) and call `VisitorMessages.start()`, which subscribes them to messages and makes them present on the channel `visitor:2018-05-25`, and unsubscribes them from all other channels.

I also have a `visitor:all` channel that everyone gets messages on and where presence is not needed.

Here's what I'm doing (please excuse the CoffeeScript):

```
VisitorMessages =
  realtime: null
  connected_first_time: false
  start: ->
    unless @realtime
      @realtime = new Ably.Realtime
        authUrl: '/auth'
        recover: (lastConnectionDetails, cb) ->
          cb(true)
          return

    @unsubscribe()

    dayChannel = @realtime.channels.get("visitor:#{day}")
    allChannel = @realtime.channels.get("visitor:all")

    allChannel.subscribe (m) ->
      switch m.name
        when " . . . "
          # . . .
    dayChannel.subscribe (m) ->
      switch m.name
        when " . . . "
          # . . .

    dayChannel.presence.subscribe 'enter', (member) -> VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel)
    dayChannel.presence.subscribe 'leave', (member) -> VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel)
    dayChannel.presence.enter()
    VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel)

    @realtime.connection.on 'connected', ->
      VisitorMessages.refreshData() # not showing this function here
      VisitorMessages.connected_first_time = true # the refreshData() function returns if this is false
      dayChannel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get("visitor:#{day}")
      dayChannel.attach()
      dayChannel.presence.enter()
      VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel)
      allChannel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get("visitor:all")
      allChannel.attach()

  setNumOnline: (channel) ->
    channel.presence.get (err, members) ->
      # I use ractive.js to manipulate the DOM
      ractive.set('number_online', members.length)

  unsubscribe: ->
    for channelName of VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.all
      unless channelName == 'visitor:all'
        channel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get(channelName)
        channel.presence.leave()
        channel.presence.unsubscribe()
        channel.unsubscribe()
        channel.detach()
        VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.release(channelName)
```

In the js console, the visitor gets a bunch of these:

```
Ably: ConnectionManager.onChannelMessage() received message with different connectionSerial, but same message id as a previous; discarding
```

Sometimes this:

```
Ably: RealtimePresence._ensureMyMembersPresent(): Presence auto-re-enter failed: [c: Unable to enter presence channel (incompatible state); code=90001]
```

And, when switching to a different date (which sets the day and calls `VisitorMessages.start()`, they get this:

```
Channels.onChannelMessage(): received event for non-existent channel: visitor:2018-05-26
```

I know that this is probably because I am explicitly releasing the channel when switching days, but when I wasn't doing that, `VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.all` would contain all of the channels that I had ever joined, and I was still receiving messages for unsubscribed channels.

So, there are a lot of different things going on here, but can someone see some big picture flaw in my approach or help me to understand why these errors are happening? Again, everything works fine, but something is not right!

Thanks!

---

Here's the above code compiled into javascript:

```
var VisitorMessages;

VisitorMessages = {
  realtime: null,
  connected_first_time: false,
  start: function() {
    var allChannel, dayChannel;
    if (!this.realtime) {
      this.realtime = new Ably.Realtime({
        authUrl: '/auth',
        recover: function(lastConnectionDetails, cb) {
          cb(true);
        }
      });
    }
    this.unsubscribe();
    dayChannel = this.realtime.channels.get("visitor:" + day);
    allChannel = this.realtime.channels.get("visitor:all");
    allChannel.subscribe(function(m) {
      switch (m.name) {
        case " . . . ":
          // . . .
      }
    });
    dayChannel.subscribe(function(m) {
      switch (m.name) {
        case " . . . ":
          // . . .
      }
    });
    dayChannel.presence.subscribe('enter', function(member) {
      VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel);
    });
    dayChannel.presence.subscribe('leave', function(member) {
      VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel);
    });
    dayChannel.presence.enter();
    VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel);
    return this.realtime.connection.on('connected', function() {
      VisitorMessages.refreshData();
      VisitorMessages.connected_first_time = true;
      dayChannel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get("visitor:" + day);
      dayChannel.attach();
      dayChannel.presence.enter();
      VisitorMessages.setNumOnline(dayChannel);
      allChannel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get("visitor:all");
      allChannel.attach();
    });
  },
  setNumOnline: function(channel) {
    channel.presence.get(function(err, members) {
      ractive.set('number_online', members.length);
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function() {
    var channel, channelName, results;
    for (channelName in VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.all) {
      if (channelName !== 'visitor:all') {
        channel = VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.get(channelName);
        channel.presence.leave();
        channel.presence.unsubscribe();
        channel.unsubscribe();
        channel.detach();
        VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.release(channelName);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Ably.

No particular big pictuer, just a bunch of different things going on here.

> Ably: ConnectionManager.onChannelMessage() received message with different connectionSerial, but same message id as a previous; discarding

This means the client lib is has received multiple copies of a message and is automatically deduplicating them. This is known to happen occasionally just after the client lib does a live comet->websocket upgrade. If it happens consistently, there may be something else going on -- contact us and we'll try and debug it live.

> Channels.onChannelMessage(): received event for non-existent channel: visitor:2018-05-26

As you correctly noted, that's because you're releasing the channel. `channels.release()` is a rarely used feature that's really only useful for when a client attaches and detaches from so many channels that `channels.all` collectively starts taking a nontrivial amount of memory, so release() deletes them so they can be garbage collected. It isn't something that 99% of people will ever need to do or know about -- I don't think it's even included in our api docs. It should certainly never be used on a channel that isn't yet detached, that'll result in undefined behaviour.

When you call it in your code, the channel is indeed not yet detached, even though you've called `detach()`. Per [the api docs for channel#detach()](https://www.ably.io/documentation/realtime/channels-messages#detach), it's an async operation -- it requests a detach from Ably, and puts the channel into the `detaching` state in the meantime. If it is necessary to release a channel (and clientside it almost never is), it should be done in the callback to `detach()` (or a `once('detached')` listener).

> when I wasn't doing that, VisitorMessages.realtime.channels.all would contain all of the channels that I had ever joined

Yup, but that's fine, being in that object doesn't mean they're attached. You can show only attached ones by filtering those entries for ones whose `state` is `'attached'`.

> and I was still receiving messages for unsubscribed channels.

Unsubscribing is a local operation (it just synchronously removes the listener you added); if you want to stop the lib from receiving messages from the server you need to detach from the channel -- see the [channels/messages docs](https://www.ably.io/documentation/realtime/channels-messages)

(If you mean your message listener is still being called after you call unsubscribe(), or the lib is still receiving messages on a channel that's in the `detached` state, neither of those should be possible -- either your unsubscribe code's broken (I don't know coffeescript too well I'm afraid), or the listener being called isn't for the channel you thought it was, or there's a bug in ably-js. Setting `log: {level: 4}` in the lib constructor will enable debug logging which can help you see what the lib is doing; and let us know if you need help analysing a log).

> `Ably: RealtimePresence._ensureMyMembersPresent(): Presence auto-re-enter failed: [c: Unable to enter presence channel (incompatible state); code=90001]`

Normally, this means a channel tried to automatically re-attach and re-enter after becoming suspended (e.g. because you were disconnected from the internet for > 2 minutes), but was unable to, e.g. because the client is now using a token that doesn't have permissions to access that channel.

But in your case I'd guess it's noise from channels that you manually release()d, and were then left in limbo as they could never be told by the server that they've been `detached`.

(I've actually just filed a feature suggestion to have a guard on channels.release() to stop you doing it for channels in active states -- https://github.com/ably/docs/issues/437 ).

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question to include the javascript version of the code (never should have posted CoffeeScript anyway).

Comment: Ok, yay. I removed the line that releases the channel, and it took care of everything except for the first error (title of the post) about the message with a different connection serial. That still happens every time when first connecting. If you can help me debug it live that would be great.

Comment: For what it's worth, where I got the idea to release the channel is here: https://www.ably.io/documentation/realtime/channels-messages#subscribe (at the end of the "Considerations" for the subscribe method)

Comment: Ok so the error in the title of the question is not an issue with my code, but an Ably issue which does not cause any problems. I'll set log to 0 in production to suppress that message on the client.